# Can't get MS Access to show "Totals"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

forgive me if I use the wrong terminology here as I am new to Access.  I am trying to show just a single field and row that shows the average amount of days between to dates.  For example, I have two fields that are pulled from a table called CheckInDate and CheckOutDate, I need to do a DateDiff on these two fields and then average all of these days and display just that single average when the query is ran.  What I have so far is below:

I created an Expression field when the query is ran to get the amount of days by using:

```
          total: DateDiff('d',[CheckInDate],[CheckOutDate])
```

My confusion is what to do next to just show the average of this new "total" field and nothing else.  I stipulate "nothing else" because I know how to add a "Totals" field at the end of the query but I am just looking to show a single field with just this average, which I am told you would use the "Totals" in the Query Tools ribbon but I can't change this from "Expression" or else it throws an error.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT Avg(DateDiff('d',[CheckInDate],[CheckOutDate])) AS total
FROM Applicants;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  New it would be an easy one.